# Javascript round(), toFixed() and toPrecision() is incorrect

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with these 3 function in javascript until I notice they all give the incorrect rounding value.
Let say the following senario

```
var x = 1.49849;
Math.round(x) //return 1, but from what I learnt from school it should be 2, right?
x.toFixed()   //return 1 too! same as rounding
x.toFixed(3)  //return 1.498, shouldn't it be 1.499?
x.toFixed(4)  //return 1.4985, at least this is working correctly....
```

I tried toPrecision() it is basically same with toFixed().

It looks like the rounding in javascript only consider one number right to it and ignored the rest of the decimal point.

Is there any javascript work around for this type of senario?

I know I can always do this in server side, but lets just focus on javascript.

Comment: please next time do your homework 1.49849 the nearest integer is 1

Comment: "but from what I learnt from school it should be 2, right?" Wrong!

Comment: round, goes to the closest integer, so 49849 in one side and 50151 in the other, same for others

Comment: Your mistake is that rounding is not applied from right to left sequentially. Round to one place is not the same as to round to two places and then to one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you are wrong.

1.49849 rounded to the nearest integer is 1, because the first digit after the decimal point is 4 which is smaller than 5.

1.49849 rounded to three digits after decimal point is 1.498 because the 4-th digit is 4.

It would be rounded up only if the first digit that you round was 5 or higher. In *some financial rounding systems*, exact halves are rounded to the nearest even number, so 2.5 rounds to 2, but 3.5 rounds to 4.